# Export webpage to Word in ASP

Tags: asp-classic, ms-word

I would like to add a button on top of a webpage, which when clicked should copy the entire webpage to an MS Word document.
This has to be done in ASP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) First create a .doc file on the server. Then create a file system object and use it to open the .doc file and write into it:

```
Set file = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wordFile = file.CreateTextFile(pathToYourDocFile, true)
wordFile.WriteLine(htmlOutput)
wordFile.close
```

"htmlOutput" must contain the page you want to export to word.

2) Another option is to directly work with an instance of Word as [mentioned on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa167258):

```
Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
wordApp.Visible = False
wordApp.Documents.Open pathToYourDocFile
Set wordApp = Nothing
```

You will need to dig [through the Word API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b9478cs.aspx) in order to write content to the document.

3) Change the content tye of your page will automatically opens it in Word (if installed on the client):

```
Response.ContentType = "application/msword"
```